# How to make loading animation with react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-bootstrap

I want to make a loading animation with react-bootstrap, while waiting for an API call. I know how I should set the state to start and stop it, I just don't know how to do it with react-bootstrap. I guess I have to use an Overlay (for the "fade" effect) and a Spinner, but not sure how.

Thank you!

Comment: When you say you "don't know how" what exactly do you mean? If you want like an example there's a spinner in react-bootstrap already with code examples, you can just use that: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/spinners/

Comment: @Jayce444 thanks for the quick response. I wanted a spinner above the main container, overlaying the content and with some "fade" effect

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve it in many ways. One very simple is with conditional rendering:
where loading is your state while you are fetching...

```
{loading?<YourComponent/>:<Spinner animation="border" role="status">
  <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
</Spinner>}
```

Comment: Thank you. Any idea how to make something similar to the animation present on react-loading-overlay (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loading-overlay) ?

Comment: I use the fade component from materialUI to create a small animation...  ```{!loading ? (
              team.map(member => (
                <Fade in={!loading} timeout={2000}>
                  <Grid item md={3}>
                    <Member teamMember={member} />
                  </Grid>
                </Fade>
              ))
            ) : (
              <Spinner />
            )}```

Comment: You may actually want to invert the condition, the way I read the code it will show the loading panel when the data is not loading anymore, while it makes sense to be the other way around

Answer (score 2):

https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/spinners/#spinners. 
After requesting with api, you can use this component until the components are loaded. Like this : 
 // First Of all import react-bootstrap Spinner Component

import {Spinner} from 'react-bootstrap'; and write like this --->

```
state = {
  exampleArray : [],
  loading : false
}

componentDidMount(){
   this.setState({
     ...this.state,
     loading: true
   })
   this.fetchItems(url);
};

fetchItems = (url) => {
   fetch(url)
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then((data) => {
    this.setState({
    loading:false,
    exampleArray : [...this.state.exampleArray, data]
   })
   })
}

render(){
return(
    {loading ? <Spinner /> : 
     exampleArray.map((arr)=> {
      return (
        <YourComponent 
          dataName : {arr.dataName}
          ............ you can pass what you want as a props

       />
      )
    })
    }



)

}
```

And you can search for animation : animation.css library. very simple to use